# AppImage and No such file or directory

Tags: bash, software-installation, minecraft

When i want to rum chmod on a Minecraft Bedrock Edition Launcher AppImage, I get a bash: no such directory or file.

I have in the file propertiers ticked the make executable option. And its not 32 bit.
It is in the Downloads folder.

I have downloaded the libgtk 3 too.

Please help

Edit

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
chmod +x Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64.0.0.661.AppImage
chmod: cannot access 'Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64.0.0.661.AppImage': No such file or directory
```

WITH LS the same

```
ls +x Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64.0.0.661.AppImage
ls: cannot access '+x': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64.0.0.661.AppImage': No such file or directory
```

Comment: edit in the command used to chmod and paste the output of `ls`

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: If you use relative path, you'd need to `cd` to the containing directory first. Or use absolute path: `chmod +x ~/Downloads/Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64.0.0.661.AppImage`

Comment: No such file or directory too

Comment: Now works with the filepath. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to run appimages in Ubuntu 22.04, install the package `libfuse2`:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

`libfuse2` is superseded by `libfuse3` and therefore is not anymore installed by default in Ubuntu 22.04, even though appimages still rely on the old version.